# How to view a normal table in SQL

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

SQL using sp_HelpText to view a stored procedure is used to view a stored procedure but what if i want to view my table,
is there any query to view my table? (I am newb to Sql and C#)

Comment: Do you want to see the table *definition* or the table's *data*?

Comment: There are a whole load of [Object Catalog Views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189783.aspx) that allow you to construct whatever query you want to obtain the metadata that's relevant to *you*. Obvious starting points are `sys.tables` and `sys.columns`.

Comment: I want to see my table statement like when we creates a table we have a query like

create table xyz

{
colummn1 varchar(10),
col2 int

}

i want to see this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sp_help "table_name" or select table & press Alt+F1 to view details of table..To View script, you need to script that using SQL server Management Studio.

Expand Database > Tables > Right Click on the table > Click on Create Script.

Thanks

Comment: Not Working any other way?

Comment: nothing happens when i press alt + F1 and there is nothing like create script

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the native INFORMATION_SCHEMA views to get table information. The following query contains a complete list of columns, data types etc for a given table without needing to join several sys views.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
    [TABLE_NAME] = 'YourTable'
```

Comment: @Ibibo could you provide any details on why please? Error messages etc?

Comment: @Ibibo - "not working" isn't helpful feedback. Do you get an *error*? (If so, what error?) No results? Different results to what you expected? (If so, *what* are your expected results?). Something else? Trying to help someone when the only feedback we're receiving is "nope, that's not it" is a frustrating experience for everyone involved.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever nods :-)

Comment: sorry don't wanna hurt u

Comment: but when we type SP_HELPTEXT and procedure name all the details and how we create procedure shown

i want to see the details of my table like 

create table ____
{
col
col
}

like this

Answer (score 0):

The table details can be viewed by pressing **Alt+F1** after highlighting the table name.